# My nav bar is broken in Firefox and not other browsers

Tags: html, css

First post.

I have looked all around the web but I'm still stuck. The website I'm creating for homework is working to plan, except with Firefox. The nav bar is stacking up. It seems like the CSS is not being applied. I've tried a lot of different things, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Here is the website - http://hills.ccsf.edu/~irose2/cnit132/hw1/index.html

HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CNIT 122 Homework</title>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bodyCenter">
        <header>
            <h1>~ Ian Rose ~</h1>
            <h2>~ CNIT 122 ~</h2>
                <nav>
                    <ul>  
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="navStyle">|</li>
                        <li><a href="publishedWebsites.html">Published Websites</a></li>
                        <li class="navStyle">|</li>
                        <li><a href="meNow.html">Me Now</a></li>
                        <li class="navStyle">|</li>
                        <li><a href="hw2.html">Homework 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
        </header> 
        <div class="mainPart">
        <article>
            <h1>Hello World!!!</h1>
                <img src="appleComputer.jpg" width="200" height="133" alt="Apple 2E Computer" title="Apple IIe Computer" class="appleComputer">
            <p>I grew up in San Francisco in the Mission and Sunset districts. I have also lived in many cities in America and traveled the country and world. This has exposed me to many diverse experiences and ideologies which have shaped me into the person I am today. 
            </p>
            <p>I became interested in Web Development as a Electrical Engineering student at City College of San Francisco. I have always had an intrest in computer programming, but only had a limited experience as a child using Basic on a Apple IIe. As taking C++ was a requirement for my Engineering studies, I jumped at the opportunity to take it my second semester. After taking the class, I found a love for all things programming related. I switched directions to the path that I am on now.
            </p>
            <p>Being an artist growing up, I started to view web technologies as a fun way to expand on these skills, while updating them and using them in a modern way. I bought a book on HTML &amp; CSS and got to work every night. About halfway through that book, which was about XHTML &amp; CSS, I decided to get a book about CSS3. I made it through that book, made a website, and kept buying more books. I got into JavaScript and started learning that language. I am taking CNIT 133 as well as this class currently.
            </p>
            <p>I hope to tighten up my Web Development skills with these courses and get an internship as my gateway to the industry.
            </p>
            <p class="goodLuck">Let's Do This!!!<br>~ Ian ~
            </p>
        </article>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>All Material &copy; Ian Rose, 2014<br>Website Designed and Developed by: <a href="mailto:&#105;&#097;&#110;&#114;&#111;&#115;&#101;&#100;&#101;&#118;&#064;&#103;&#109;&#097;&#105;&#108;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109;">Ian Rose</a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhills.ccsf.edu%2F~irose2%2Fcnit132%2Fhw1%2Findex.html" target="_blank">
                    <img class="w3cLogo" src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/badge/html5-badge-h-solo.png" width="33" height="34" alt="HTML5 Powered" title="HTML5 Powered">
                </a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhills.ccsf.edu%2F~irose2%2Fcnit132%2Fhw1%2Fstyles.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en;lang=en" target="_blank">
                    <img class="cssValidated" src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss-blue" alt="Valid CSS!">
                </a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <script>
                    var dateModified = document.lastModified;
                    mydate = dateModified;
                    document.write("Last updated: " + mydate);
                </script>
            </p>
        </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS -

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy);
html {
    background-color: #232393;
    background-image: url("zenbg-1.png");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
 }
.bodyCenter {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
header {
    border-style: none; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.82);
    background-image: url(ianAndPenguin.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat ;
    background-position: 99.3%;
    margin-top: 12px;
    height: 180px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
header h1 {
    font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
    font-size: 3em; 
    text-align: center;
    color: #1617b1;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin: 0px;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 5px 7px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.94);
    -moz-text-shadow: 5px 7px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.94);
    text-shadow: 5px 7px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.94);
   } 
header h2 {
    font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
    font-size: 4em; 
    text-align: center;
    color: #1617b1;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin: 0px;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 5px 7px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.94);
    -moz-text-shadow: 5px 7px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.94);
    text-shadow: 5px 7px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.94);
    margin-top: -42px;
    }
nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;   
}
nav a {
    display: block;
    width: inherit;
    margin-top: -30px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: #2bac38;
}
.navStyle {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.active {
    color: #000;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 5px 7px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.84);
    -moz-text-shadow: 5px 7px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.84);
    text-shadow: 3px 3px .5px rgba(14, 167, 199, .6);
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
article h1 {
    font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
    font-size: 44px;
    color: #1617b1;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 5px 7px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.94);
    -moz-text-shadow: 5px 7px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.94);
    text-shadow: 5px 7px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.94);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
article h2 { 
    font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #1617b1;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 3px 5px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.94);
    -moz-text-shadow: 3px 5px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.94);
    text-shadow: 3px 5px 7px rgba(33, 182, 211, 0.94);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
article p  {
    font-family: sans-serif, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.mainPart {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.82);
    border-style: none; 
    border-color: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.goodLuck {
    font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
    font-size: 24px;  
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
footer {
    border-style: none; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.82);
    height: 133px;
    padding: 2px 3px 3px 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif, serif;
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #000;
}
.w3cLogo {
    float: left;
}
.cssValidated {
    border: 0; 
    width: 88px; 
    height: 31px; 
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.appleComputer {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Thank You for any help!

~Ian~

Comment: Hi, i have opened the link in firefox as well as chrome, both looks similar, can you please provide JSFiddle code or a screenshot of firefox browser

Comment: Hi Devang. Thank you for the fast reply! I can't upload pictures yet but here is the link to a screenshot. http://hills.ccsf.edu/~irose2/cnit132/hw1/screenShot.jpg

Comment: Can’t reproduce that either (FF 31.0/Win7). Have you tried clearing your browser cache already?

Comment: Yes, and using private mode on two different Macs. I'd love if it was a problem on my end,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you actually mean is the website's menu, not navbar. Just like you, I have reproduced the issue in FF, seems to be working well in Safari.

You should change the way you align the list to the left. There are a couple of lines you better be taking off.

Remove these lines from given CSS blocks:

```
nav a {
    display: block; /* delete */
}
.navStyle {
    margin-top: -30px; /* delete */
}
```

Now you should be able to see the menu correctly but in wrong position. To fix it, you should add a negative margin to your `ul` element or `nav`.

For example:

```
nav {
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Better, eh? Though your code has problems. This isn't the correct way to make a CSS menu with separators. I recommend you to take a look to these articles and review their code, you'll see that they are a lot more clear and effective.
http://idearays.com/blog/using-separators-in-lists-menu-with-css/
http://www.jackreichert.com/2011/07/31/how-to-add-a-divider-between-menu-items-in-css-using-only-one-selector/
http://code.adonline.id.au/simple-css-menu-separators-for-navigation/

Comment: Thank you kubilay!I had a feeling I was going at it the wrong way. I'll rewrite the code before I submit it.